# Write a unicode text at inifiles

Tags: delphi

How i can write the unicode string "Внимание" on a .inifile?
how i'm writing:

```
    Escreve := TIniFile.Create(Patch + 'File.ini');
    Escreve.WriteString('Informations', 'Patch',  ParamStr(0));
```

The folder name is "Внимание" and at .inifile show ????????

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you want to share the solution you've found, do so by using the space below with the heading **Your Answer**. For more information, see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, `TIniFile` internally uses the Win32 PrivateProfile API (in this case, [`WritePrivateProfileStringA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestringa) in Delphi 2007 and earlier, and [`WritePrivateProfileStringW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestringw) in Delphi 2009 and later). `WritePrivateProfileStringA()` does not support Unicode at all, and `WritePrivateProfileStringW()` writes Unicode data only if the INI file already exists and was created with a UTF-16 BOM, otherwise it writes ANSI data instead.

If you are using Delphi 2009+, [`TMemIniFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile) allows you to specify a [`TEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding) for the desired charset, such as `TEncoding.UTF8` or `TEncoding.Unicode` (UTF-16), eg:

```pascal
Escreve := TMemIniFile.Create(Patch + 'File.ini', TEncoding.UTF8);
Escreve.WriteString('Informations', 'Patch',  ParamStr(0));
```

Comment: You know how call the CreateProcess routine using the string who have unicode? because it don't start the app and don't return any error.

Comment: @PSDEVS that issue has nothing to do with this question about INI files. Please don't try to hijack questions. If you have an unrelated question, make a new post about it. That being said, use `CreateProcessW()` when using Unicode strings.

Comment: Hello, I found out that tmeminifile is not thread safe, is it possible? right now i'm using tinifile in threads without any problems, but changing tmeminifile created problems inside threads. is there an equivalent thread safe? or the only solution to use ini with utf8 is to add critical sections and use tmemini? thank you

Comment: @lorife TIniFile is not thread safe, either. Most classes are not. Yes, you would have to wrap the INI file operations with synchronization, such as a critical section, mutex, TMonitor, etc

Comment: ok, thanks. One last question. Isn't TIniFile thread safe if used just to read?