# how to set German alphabet corretly in Tlabeledit

Tags: delphi, utf-8, character

i use this code to read my inifile and host it to Tlabeledit . but the result appears like this > Griesener StraÃŸe insted of Griesener Straße ! so 'ß' changed to 'ÃŸ' !

in my inifile all the alphabets are correct .

How can i solve this problem !
(i have too keep UTF-8)

i use this

```
procedure TDlg_XRechnung.INIDatei_einlesen;
var NeueSeite : TTabSheet;
  i,l: Integer;
  MeinEdit : TLabeledEdit;
begin
  try
    INIDatei                := TIniFile.Create(INIDateiname);
    Version                 := INIDatei.ReadInteger('INI','Version', 1);
    DebugMode               := INIDatei.ReadInteger('INI','DebugMode', 0);
    PDFDatei                := INIDatei.ReadString('PDF','PDFName', '');
    XRechnungDatei          := INIDatei.ReadString('PDF','XInvoice', '');
    Edit_LeitwegeID.Text    := INIDatei.ReadString('InvData','BT-10', '');
    Edit_Bestellnummer.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvData','BT-13', '');
    Edit_Projektreferenz.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvData','BT-11', '');
    Edit_Vertragsnummer.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvData','BT-12', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsnummer.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvData','BT-1', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsdatum.Date := INIDatei.ReadDate('InvData','BT-2', now);
    Edit_Leistungsdatum.Date := INIDatei.ReadDate('InvData','BT-9', now);
    Edit_Bemerkung.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvData','BT-22', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Name.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvErst','BT-27', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsersteller_UST_ID.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvErst','BT-31', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Adresse.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvErst','BT-35', '') + INIDatei.ReadString('InvErst','BT-36', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsersteller_PLZ.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvErst','BT-38', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Ort.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvErst','BT-37', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Land.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvErst','BT-40', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Name.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvEmp','BT-44','');
    Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Adresse.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvEmp','BT-50', '') + INIDatei.ReadString('InvEmp','BT-51', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_PLZ.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvEmp','BT-53', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Ort.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvEmp','BT-52', '');
    Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Land.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('InvEmp','BT-55', '');
    Edit1test.Text :=  INIDatei.ReadString('POS','001BT-129', '');


    AnzahlPositinen := INIDatei.ReadInteger('POS','AnzPos', 1);
    for i := 1 to AnzahlPositinen do
    begin
      NeueSeite := TTabSheet.Create(PC_Positionen);
      NeueSeite.PageControl := PC_Positionen;
      NeueSeite.Caption := 'Position ' + IntToStr(i);

      MeinEdit := TLabeledEdit.Create(Self);
      MeinEdit.Left := 10;
      MeinEdit.Top  := 20;
      MeinEdit.Name := 'Artikelnummer' +IntToStr(i);
      MeinEdit.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('POS', '00' + IntToStr(i) +  'BT-153','');
      MeinEdit.EditLabel.Caption := 'Artikelnummer';
      MeinEdit.Width := 175;
      MeinEdit.LabelPosition := lpAbove;
      MeinEdit.Parent := NeueSeite;

    
    end;

  finally
    INIDatei.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Use `TMemIniFile` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961971/write-a-unicode-text-at-inifiles

Comment: Thanks . your comment solve my problem ! just Use TMemIniFile instead  .

Comment: Great, then I close this Q as a duplicate of the linked one.